# Set target tab on pageload with jquery?

Tags: jquery, tabs

I'm trying to figure out how to set a target tab on pageload so that the first tab is always open! Ive seen similar solutions that do not work in my case.

-The tabs are all different sizes, so I haven't been able to do anything involving position:absolute
-I can not add #c1 to the link that brings them to the page.

http://buildmyled-sandbox.mybigcommerce.com/12-000k-reef-spectrum-fixture/#c1

In this example I need "#c1" to be added to the URL every time.

Comment: What specific issue are you having? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can bring focus to the element using something like:

```
$(window).scrollTop($('#c1').position().top);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send a click event to the desired tab like this:

```
$(".tabs-nav a").first().click()
```

Modify the selector (`.tabs-nav a`) as needed to target the link you want.